# Variable mysql statement in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a variable that is a filter for my query:

```
$filterString.=" AND venue = ".$venue;
```

And I want this variable (when called) to add the AND filter statement to my query.

My query is as follows (with the failed attempt):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event 
WHERE city = '$city' " . $filterString . " 
ORDER BY date ASC");
```

Comment: Please don't do this (substitute user-suplied data directly into an SQL query). You're allowing an SQL injection attack. Instead use a "prepared statement" (data-binding of placeholders in the query).

Comment: Even if I use mysql_real_escape_string?

Comment: @David-SkyMesh ... How do you know that `$city` and `$venue` are "user-suplied data"

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: Supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: @Fabian oh, just call it an overwhelming sense of typical reality - that and piecing together clues from other comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `venue` needs to be surrounded by single quotes:

```
$filterString.=" AND venue = '".$venue.".";
```

However, it is better to use parameterized queries, instead of embedding queries directly in the SQL string.

Comment: You can bind an additional parameter that controls (logically) whether the AND statement has effect. e.g: ` where city = ? and ((not ?) or venue = ?))`

Comment: it would be better if you showed @pedrum how to do the parameterised query, as well as the logical inclusion/exclusion of the filter.

Comment: Is there any way to have a WHERE something = Anything?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$filterString .= !empty($venue) ? " AND venue = '$venue'" : '';
```

Substitute whatever test you want at the start, the idea is to return a blank string if $venue doesn't apply to the filter.

To answer your other comment question:

```
WHERE 1
```

is a valid condition that works like *Anything*